# I'm using ffmpeg with Windows 10 and I need to convert all files to mov

Tags: ffmpeg

I can do one file using this line for example:

```
ffmpeg -i LostInTranslation.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy LostInTranslation.mov
```

But I want to convert all the mp4's on my desktop so I tried this line:

```
for i in *mp4; do ffmpeg -i $i -vcodec copy -acodec copy $i.mov; done
```

All I get is `i was unexpected at this time.` Both these lines used to work for me when I was using a mac. Now with windows 10 its just not working and I know nothing about `ffmpeg` besides just copy and paste the lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FFtip #43: You can shorten it by replacing `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` with `-c copy`.

Answer (score 3):

You're using BASH in Windows, and it will not work without the proper setup.

Create a batch file with the following:

`for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%%~dpna.mov"`

This should get the results you want.

Make sure you use a direct path to ffmpeg like `d:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe`

As an example, these are some of the lines in my `encode.bat` file:

```
REM for /R %%c in ("*.mkv") do D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%c" -c:v copy -c:a copy -flags +global_header "%%~dpnc.mp4" && del "%%c"
REM for /R %%d in ("*.mpg") do D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%d" -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc vbr -qmin 16 -qmax 60 -cq 32 -preset hq -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -movflags +faststart "%%~dpnd.mkv"
REM for /R %%a in ("*.mp4") do D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%a" -c:v hevc_nvenc -r 24 -rc vbr -qmin 16 -qmax 60 -q:v 1 -cq 28 -preset hq -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -movflags +faststart "%%~dpna.mkv" && del "%%a"
REM for /R %%b in ("*.avi") do D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%b" -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc vbr -qmin 16 -qmax 60 -cq 32 -preset hq -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -movflags +faststart "%%~dpnb.mkv"
REM for /R %%a in ("*.mp4") do D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%a" -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc vbr -qmin 16 -qmax 60 -cq 28 -preset hq -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags +global_header -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -movflags +faststart "%%~dpna.mkv" && del "%%a"
```

I pick and choose which lines I want to use as required, and make adjustments.

Keep in mind that the `/R` is for recursive, and the `del "%%a"` deletes the original file after conversion.  *Be very careful with this.*

Comment: You can remove `-movflags +faststart` for your Matroska outputs: that's an option for the MOV/MP4/M4A muxer.

Comment: Agreed.  They're leftovers from others, I just never got round to it, and they didn't hurt the process (read "lazy") :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/features/) in Ubuntu to achieve similar results.

Click on `File` and choose `Transcode Clips`

A dialog below will be presented.

[image: Transcoding with GUI]

Choose your source and destination file(s)

Choose the profile you want to use

Click `Start`

As a side note, I personally think kdenlive is lookin' really nice with a dark theme.

Comment: Remember to comment downvoter

Comment: kdenlive is available for Linux, however he stated he's using Windows 10.  Also, it might be helpful to add a more thorough explanation with a step by step guide. That's the only reason I downvoted.  Happy to upvote if fixed :)

Comment: Ok, I'll add screeenshots

Comment: Good stuff.  Increasing the quality of an answer makes it better for everyone, providing different points of view, and possible fixes :)